# How to calculate the new coordinate of node after a transformation in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, graphics

I've a simple group with a rectangle and a circle. The position of the rectangle is (100,0), I get this value from the Bound in Parent.

[image]

If I apply a transformation to the `Group`, e.g. `scale = -1`, the bounds in the parent of the rectangle are still (100,0) instead of (0,0).

[image]

So how can I calculate the new coordinate of node respect the parent?

Comment: Coordinate with respect to which coordinate system?

Comment: Respect to the Parent, theoretically the node coordinates relative to the Group should be (0,0)

Comment: Well, no. When you apply a transform to the `Group`, you change its coordinate system. The coordinates you see **are** the node coordinates relative to the `Group`. With `scaleX=-1`, the origin of the `Group` is in its top *right*, and the `x` coordinate increases *right to left*. So the top right of the rectangle is, as reported, at `(100,0)`, and the top left is at `(189,0)` (which appears to be the top left of the `Group`). I guess: can you explain more what you're trying to do?

Comment: I would always need to know the position of the rectangle (top left corner). Now, if I rotate the group, how can I calculate the new position of the rectangle (top left corner)?

Comment: Again, the positions of the corners relative to the group don’t change when you transform the group.